# Multiple inputs validator in angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to build a validator that gets from a text input an email address, and it checks if the email already exists in a list of emails that i want to send as a parameter somehow

The code looks like this :

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[noDuplicatedEmails]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: DuplicatedEmailDirective, multi: true}]
})

export class DuplicatedEmailDirective implements Validator {
  @Input('recipientEmail') recipientEmail = '';

  validate(control: AbstractControl, recipients: ShareRecipient[]): ValidationErrors | null {
    if (!control.value) {
      return null;
    }
    const emailAlreadyAdded = recipients.some(shareRecipient => shareRecipient.email === control.value);
    return emailAlreadyAdded ? { duplicatedEmail : true } : null;
  }
}
```

But sending a second parameter as a param doesn't seem to work, i get the following error on the validate method:

TS2416: Property 'validate' in type 'DuplicatedEmailDirective' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Validator'.   Type '(control: AbstractControl, recipients: ShareRecipient[]) => ValidationErrors' is not assignable to type '(control: AbstractControl) => ValidationErrors'.

Any ideas on how to fix this or a workaround?

Comment: your error message indicates that you can't define the validate method using recipients as a parameter.

You can achieve what you want by fetching the recipients array from within the function. Where is your email list stored ? How can you access it ?

Comment: @AlexandreFERRERA , the array is stored in the component where i will use the validator, it is is stored as public class variable

Comment: In that case, I could recommend you to use an @Attribute
Here's an example of a similar situation with the solution: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-implement-a-custom-validator-directive-confirm-password-in-angular-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be to pass `recipients` as Input to DuplicatedEmailDirective:

```ts
    @Input('recipients') recipients: ShareRecipient[] = [];
```

and define `validate` method as:

```ts
    validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
        if (!control.value) {
          return null;
        }
        const emailAlreadyAdded = this.recipients.some(shareRecipient => shareRecipient.email === control.value);
        return emailAlreadyAdded ? { duplicatedEmail : true } : null;
    }
```

Example from Angular docs: [Adding custom validators to template-driven forms](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-custom-validators-to-template-driven-forms)

Comment: And where should i write that part with @Input and so on?

Comment: Both `@Input` and `validate` are part of `DuplicatedEmailDirective` class. You can then pass `recipients` value from the host element on which you would be using your directive.